# Why is glBufferSubData slow?

Tags: c++, opengl

When trying to access GL_ARRAY_BUFFER using glBufferSubData to 128 byte buffer size, accessing takes at worst 200 microseconds. Instead when allocating whole buffer again with glBufferData it takes only 3 microseconds. I had similar issues with glGetBufferSubData. My CPU is an i5 8600k and the GPU is a GTX 1080 Ti.

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(mat4) * 2, matrices.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW); // 3 us
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(mat4) * index, sizeof(mat4), matrix.data()); // at worst 200 us

using namespace std::chrono;
// same measurement for both cases
auto timer = high_resolution_clock::now();
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(mat4) * 2, matrices.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
std::cout << duration_cast<microseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - timer).count() << '\n';
```

Comment: Without knowing how you measure this, it is not really possible to give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: And what hardware?

Comment: I added hardware and the way I measure the time. I can also see the impact in fps so I assume the measuring is not wrong.

Comment: All of this depends on what you do before/after with the buffer. It might be that internally OpenGL blocks at glBufferSubData because it needs to flush the command buffer while glBufferData allocates a new buffer and orphans the old one.

Comment: For many OpenGL commands, the invocation of the commands does not necessarily mean that all work is already done when the function call finished.  For `glBufferSubData`  the driver might need to do some locking/synchronization right at the time when the command is called, to guarantee consistency. For `glBufferData` it might be able to do that synchronization at a later point.

Comment: So for constantly changing the data, is it better to always rewrite whole buffer since its faster or is there any other method that I could use to edit the buffer without any performance problems? Because I think its not very efficient to always rewrite the things when you could just edit one thing.

Comment: This cannot be said in general. You need to measure more than just the individual API call. The possible delayed _"housekeeping"_ the driver has to do for `glBufferData` could be detectable if you measure the whole pipeline. So using `glBufferData` could be slower in your overall pipeline then using `glBufferSubData`. But `glBufferSubData` could also be slower if it is invoked at a time when the driver needs to wait longer for synchronization, then it would take to create a new buffer.

Comment: The VBO is too small to draw any conclusions, it might very well be possible that the overhead of subData call is larger than that of creating a new buffer.

Comment: This is also with glGetBufferSubData. I don't see how reading buffer would be slow. Or maybe it is just waiting for synchronization. Only solution I see now is that I store things in ram and get data from ram instead of vram, but that's a bit waste to keep both datas in vram and ram.

Answer (score 0):

This question might be overdue for an answer, but today I was considering using glGetBufferSubData and noticed a bit of lag despite running the and NVidia GEFORCE RTX 3060. There was a 0.006 second to download data to the CPU/RAM and a 0 second time to load to the GPU. I would suggest keeping a copy of your matrix in RAM and store the index of where the matrix is in the shader storage buffer so you can update it later in you program if you like. That is what I am doing at least.

You can see my original post here: [Is it efficient to download matrix to CPU/RAM to update it and send it back to GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72092822/is-it-efficient-to-download-matrix-to-cpu-ram-to-update-it-and-send-it-back-to-g/72093318#72093318)