# Is it efficient to download matrix to CPU/RAM to update it and send it back to GPU?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, matrix, opengl, game-engine

I am making a 2D game engine. I am trying to optimize my transformation matrices for all game objects created. Right now, transformation matrices are stored in RAM and they are loaded to the GPU every frame. That means that I have data redundancy in RAM and GPU. I know it is possible to read data from the GPU to the RAM/CPU. I was thinking of loading the transformation matrix to the GPU. Then, every time I need to update, get the data to the CPU/RAM, made the matrix updates and load it back to the GPU. This raises the question:

Would reading from the GPU to the CPU/RAM to update only matrices right when they are updated and load it back to the GPU be efficient or not?

Note that this would mean that I would not have to load the matrix every frame to the GPU if it did not update in between frames. Answers out of the scope of the question are welcomed.

Update: these matrices are stored in a shader storage buffer.

Update: I guess it boils down to this, is reading from shader storage buffers efficient for what i am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Is there a way to reserve GPU memory?  For example, place your identity matrix at the start of GPU memory.  Load anything else after the end of the matrix.  My understanding is that a GPU doesn't automatically clear all its memory for each load.

Comment: I am not concerned with clearing the memory of the GPU. The plan is to make a shader storage buffer big enough to hold as many matrices need and recize it as needed.

Comment: How about storing the matrix in a persistently mapped SSBO? But nevertheless, I highly doubt that the storage of a bunch of matrices is something you should be concerned about. A matrix is usually stored as 12 or 16 floats, which means a total memory consumption between 48 and 64 bytes.

Comment: You are correct, but when I multiply that by how ever many objects I create later on like complex 2d particle systems, then it becomes important. Or many particle systems.

Comment: Lets say i have 100,000 game objects with matrices, that would men 6.4 megabytes in RAM and GPU. Plus, the 3.2 megabytes in data transfer every frame... and that is not taking into account the components that they will definitely have. Would it matter then?

Answer (score 0):

After some benchmarking using clock() from time.h it is safe to say that glGetBufferSubData is slower than glBufferSubData. Loading to the GPU was so fast that the delta time would always read 0 seconds and reading from the shader storage buffer took 0.006 seconds. That can quickly escalate to big numbers when multiplied by n number of game objects in a scene. I suggest to myself and others to only use glGetBufferSubData the least amount possible. The idea sounded good in theory. I was counting on the Big-O efficiency to be the same for both functions, but it is not.

Comment: I don't think you can get an accurate estimate of how long `glBufferSubData` takes as it may be an asynchronous function queuing up a data transfer and semaphore to transfer the data either at a more opportune moment or when it is absolutely needed. `glGetBufferSubData` can't do that as the operations need to be observable immediately upon completion.